# shadowing iteration variable inside for loop

Tags: for-loop, go, shadowing

I am new to the Go programming language and find a strange behaviour.
Go allows me to redefine a variable of the same name as the iteration variable.
I need an explanation. Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    run()
    fmt.Scanln()
}

func run() {
    for x := 1; x < 10; x++ {
        x := x // How is this possible?
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: `x := x` creates a new, distinct variable from the loop variable `x` (but initialized with `x`). And then the launched goroutine will use / refer to this copy. Else it would be a data race.

Comment: It's possible because variables named `x` are declared in different blocks.  See [Declarations and Scope](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). See also [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines).